# Jars created through Maven job from Git does not work

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

My project requires me to create a runnable jar from a certain maven build job(using jenkinsfile) and use the jar as a test utility.

Now, When I running the pom.xml and building the jar from my local machine, The jar is gettting created and I am able to run it in my test without any issue. But, when I am creating the same jar after checking in the code in Git, the jar created is substantially smaller in size(30kb) and does not run. 
Using a decompiler, i verified the contents of the jars and found that none of the dependencies are getting merged with the jars created from Git. I am not sure where things are going wrong since all the dependencies are merged in the jar generated when I am running the pom through local. 
Please find the console log for jar generated through local. I have also attached the decompiled jars snapshots.

Request you to please help me in this.

Comment: None of your attachments actually made it into your question, but that aside, the problem of dependencies not making it into a Maven build is a very well known and solved one.  Research on Stack Overflow for Maven plugins which can help you here.

Comment: Missing pom file and the steps you have used to build...